# Queries to select records at specific time intervals?

Tags: sql, sql-server, timestamp

I have the following data:

```
X,        Y,        Receiver, Timestamp 
1.534268, 51.03796, 126,      2017-06-01 02:01:01 
1.534268, 51.03793, 126,      2017-06-01 02:03:01 
1.534268, 51.03799, 133,      2017-06-01 02:05:01 
1.534268, 51.03716, 133,      2017-06-01 02:09:01 
1.534268, 51.03766, 126,      2017-06-01 02:10:01 
1.534268, 51.03766, 126,      2017-06-01 02:17:01 
1.534268, 51.03795, 126,      2017-06-01 02:19:01 
1.534268, 51.03791, 133,      2017-06-01 02:22:01 
1.534268, 51.03746, 126,      2017-06-01 02:24:01 
1.534268, 51.03796, 133,      2017-06-01 02:31:01
```

I need SQL queries to do two things:

1. Select records at roughly 10 minute intervals, so I end up with something like this:

```
X,        Y,        Receiver, Timestamp 
1.534268, 51.03796, 126,      2017-06-01 02:01:01 
1.534268, 51.03766, 126,      2017-06-01 02:10:01 
1.534268, 51.03795, 126,      2017-06-01 02:19:01 
1.534268, 51.03796, 133,      2017-06-01 02:31:01
```

How would I then modify the query to select data at 15 minute, 30 minute and hourly intervals?

2. From the results above, how would I get a count the number of records that fall under each receiver i.e.

```
Receiver 126: 3,
Receiver 133: 1
```

Comment: Your rules for identifying the start of a record are unclear.  Sometimes, it is within 10 minutes.  Sometimes it is not.  You need to provide more information on how you want to split the data up.

Comment: Do you have primary key on this table, would be more efficient to write a query

Comment: The timestamps are never going to be precisely 10 minutes apart. So I need sequential records that are the closest to 10 minutes apart. The first record is: 02:01:01, so the next record selected should be 02:10:01 as it’s the closest to 10 min in difference from the first record. If that makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"something like this".  Well, the simplest thing to do is to take the first record from the "calendar clock" each ten minutes.  That would be the first record after 00:00, 00:10, 00:20, and so on.

For this, you can use `first_value()` and `select distinct`:

```
select distinct
       first_value(x) over (partition by dd, hh, mm order by timestamp) as x,
       first_value(y) over (partition by dd, hh, mm order by timestamp) as y,
       first_value(receiver) over (partition by dd, hh, mm order by timestamp) as receiver,
       min(timestamp) over (partition by dd, hh, mm),
       count(*) over (partition by dd, hh, mm) as cnt

from t cross apply
     (values (convert(date, timestamp), datepart(hour, timestamp), datepart(minute, timestamp) / 6)
     ) v(dd, hh, mm);
```

This does not return exactly the results you specified but it seems to meet the conditions mentioned in the question.

EDIT:

It strikes me that you might want 10 minutes intervals *starting from the first timestamp*.  If so:

```
select (case when seqnum = 1 then x end) as x,
       (case when seqnum = 1 then y end) as y,
       (case when seqnum = 1 then receiver end) as receiver,
       min(timestamp),
       count(*)
from (select t.*,
             datediff(second, min_ts, timestamp) / (10 * 60) as grp,
             row_number() over (partition by datediff(second, min_ts, timestamp) / (10 * 60) order by timestamp) as seqnum,
      from (select t.*,
                   min(timestamp) over () as min_ts
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by grp;
```

I think this returns the groups that you specify.
    group by grp;

Answer (score 0):

Use below query,

Result1:

```
select t1.* from table t1
inner join t2
on (datediff(minute, starttime, endtime) = 10);
```

Result2:

```
select x, t, reciever, count(1)
from
(select t1.* from table t1
inner join t2
on (datediff(minute, starttime, endtime) = 10)) qry
group by x, t, reciever;
```

Comment: It was good of you to to clean up the data into images, except that on SO both code and data should be formatted text - not images. Something to keep in mind for the future.